# Django CBV dispatch method valid syntax

Tags: python, django, django-views

Are declaring variables in dispatch method valid in following sample code? 
if not is there better coding standards in CBV? my idea is avoiding redeclare the same variable in every http methods

```
class MyClsName(View):
   template_name = "setup/code_install.html"

   def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
       self.name = request.session['name']
       self.obj = MyModel.objects.get(Name=self.name)
       return super(MyClsName, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)

   def get(self, request):
       # obj = MyModel.objects.get(Name=self.name) --> to avoid
       context = {'account': self.obj}
       return render(request, self.template_name, context)

   def post(self, request):
       # obj = MyModel.objects.get(Name=self.name) --> to avoid
       context = {'account': self.obj}
       return render(request, self.template_name, context)
```

Comment: yup, doing in `dispatch` is totally ok

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not invalid, but it is definitely not taking advantage of the features of class-based views. It is rarely necessary to overwrite either of dispatch or get/post. Instead, you should choose a more appropriate view to subclass, and override the specific methods it provides. In this case, since you want to display a single object, the appropriate base class is DetailView, and the method to override is `get_object`.

```
class MyClsName(DetailView):
    template_name = "setup/code_install.html"

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return MyModel.objects.get(Name=self.request.session['name'])
```

Note no need to define dispatch, get, or post at all.

Comment: thanks for pointing out, in my case i would need both get and post methods